# powershell Combine WMI Query results into one table

Tags: powershell, wmi

I want to grab disk information from multiple computers and output it.

This works:

```
foreach ($args in $file) {
    get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Credential $cre -ComputerName $args -Filter "Drivetype=3"  | 
    ft SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,@{Label="Total Size";Expression={$_.Size / 1gb -as [int] }},@{Label="Free Size";Expression={$_.freespace / 1gb -as [int] }} -autosize
}
```

but the output looks like this:

```
SystemName DeviceID VolumeName Total Size Free Size
---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------
Computer1  C:       OS                100        31
Computer1  D:       DATA              500       200



SystemName DeviceID VolumeName Total Size Free Size
---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------
Computer2  C:       OS                110        48
Computer2  D:       DATA              500       201



SystemName DeviceID VolumeName Total Size Free Size
---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------
Computer3  C:       OS                100        38
Computer3  D:       DATA              500       260
```

I would like them combined so the output looks like this:

```
SystemName DeviceID VolumeName Total Size Free Size
---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------
Computer1  C:       OS                100        31
Computer1  D:       DATA              500       200
Computer2  C:       OS                110        48
Computer2  D:       DATA              500       201
Computer3  C:       OS                100        38
Computer3  D:       DATA              500       260
```

I've looked into creating a new object, but I'm unsure how to add the WMI query results to that object in a loop under the same header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `foreach` loop with the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet and move `Format-Table` (`ft`) to the very end of the pipeline:

```
$file |ForEach-Object {
    Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Credential $cre -ComputerName $_ -Filter "Drivetype=3" 
} |Format-Table SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,@{Label="Total Size";Expression={$_.Size / 1gb -as [int] }},@{Label="Free Size";Expression={$_.freespace / 1gb -as [int] }} -autosize
```

*(also, don't use `$args` like that, it's an [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx))*

---

If you plan on using the output from WMI later in your script, use `Select-Object` instead of `Format-Table`.

Then use `Format-Table` when you need to *display* it:

```
$LogicalDisks = $file |ForEach-Object {
    Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Credential $cre -ComputerName $_ -Filter "Drivetype=3" 
} |Select-Object SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,@{Label="Total Size";Expression={$_.Size / 1gb -as [int] }},@{Label="Free Size";Expression={$_.freespace / 1gb -as [int] }}

# Do some stuff with $LogicalDisks
# ...

# Time to display the disks to the user
$LogicalDisks |Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: A little more as to why this works like it does. The `ForEach` loop as used in the OP will process and output each item individually to its own execution of `Format-Table`. The `ForEach-Object` functions within the pipe, and while it does process each item individually, it collects the results of all of the output for the next part of the pipe, and a single execution of the `Format-Table` cmdlet with all of the data.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. I believe I understand how for For-EachObject works now

Comment: Also, I believe I'm using $args correctly. Further up in the script that I did not include is `$defaultServerList = 'computers.txt'` and `$file = get-Content $defaultServerList`

Comment: @ElectronicDrug It's not that your *using* it incorrectly, it's that you should use that *name*, call it anything else. `foreach($computer in $file){ ... }` Also conveys meaning

Comment: Ah, I gotcha. Thank you.